# Parsing json Object and appending to recyclerview

Tags: java, android, json

I am just starting to learn java and Android , Ia m trying to parse json data and apply the data to recyclerview but i am not able to do it. here is my code

```
public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));
                //GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerLarger(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_LARGER));

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));
                GetDataAdapter2.setMrp_price(json.getString(JSON_MRP_PRICE));
                GetDataAdapter2.setDisc_price(json.getString(JSON_DISC_PRICE));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
```

And here is my JSON Response

```
{"118":{"garment_color":"Blue","garment_name":"skjhkds","garment_price":"232"},"119":{"garment_color":"hjsadjjs","garment_name":"sdasd","garment_price":"23478"}}
```

Please someone give a brief explanation of the correct code. it would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: you should implement `JsonObjectRequest` , response is an object

Comment: _You_ need to tell _us_ what the correct code should be doing.  Your JSON response is well-formed, and therefore in the absence of any other information it is already valid.

Comment: where have you defined JSON_IMAGE_URL JSON_DISC_PRICE.?

Comment: you are passing jsonArray in method JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL but json formate that you have given is in json object.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh can you tell how the code should be using JsonObjectRequest

Comment: @PratikTank can you tell me how to parse JSON Object

Answer (score 0):

```
rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(getActivity());
recyclerview.setAdapter(rvAdapterHScode);
rvAdapter.set(responce.getcodes());
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
```

then in adapter
accept the set values
or

call your response inside the recyclerview adapter

Answer (score 0):

[like this way](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)
your jsonArray should be in following way:

```
{
"jArray": [{
        "id": "118",
        "garment_color": "Blue",
        "garment_name": "skjhkds",
        "garment_price": "232"
    },
    {
        "id": "119",
        "garment_color": "hjsadjjs",
        "garment_name": "sdasd",
        "garment_price": "23478"
    }
]
}
```

then read that json like this way:

```
// Getting JSON Array node
    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("jArray");

    // looping through All Contacts
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
        try {
            GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(c.getString("garment_name"));
            GetDataAdapter2.setMrp_price(c.getString("garment_price"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }
    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. But I cannot change the format of json. Can you tell how to parse the json object which I mentioned in the question. it would be very helpful. Thanks